# getpagesize() vs. sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)

Tags: linux, unix, mmap, system-configuration

Both in general and with regard to cross-platform support, is one function -- getpagesize() vs. sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) -- more reliable than the other?

Answer (score 7):

After some additional searching, I've discovered that `getpagesize()` was deprecated in [POSIX issue 6](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap01.html), and removed in [POSIX issue 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap03.html).  It's recommended to use `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is also what `man getpagesize` says: "_In SUSv2 the getpagesize() call is labeled LEGACY, and in POSIX.1-2001 it has been dropped_" and: "_Portable applications should employ sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) instead of getpagesize()_"